# Checking how many elements a set contains

Tags: scala, boolean, set, element

I need to write a function that returns true if a set (this set is the output of another function) contains 1 element and otherwise it leaves the set as it is.

For example:

Set(1) returns a specific result and Set(2,4) returns the set as it is.

How can I check how many elements a set contains?

Comment: why don't you base your condition upon the `Set`'s `size` method ?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/#scala.collection.Set

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need the `size` method on a Set:

```
scala> Set(1).size
res0: Int = 1

scala> Set(1,2).size
res1: Int = 2
```

See also the [documentation for Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html).

Let's say your other function is called `getSet`. So all you need to do is call it, then check the size of the resulting `Set`, and return a value depending on that size. For example, I shall assume that if the set's size is 1, we need to return a special value (a Set containing the value 99) - but just replace this with whatever specific result you actually need to return.

```
def mySet = {
  val myset = getSet()
  if (myset.size == 1) Set(99)  // return special value
  else myset  // return original set unchanged
}
```

Comment: Rather than use **special** return types that may confuse due to being **magical**, why not use a return type of `Option[Set[A]]` where `A` is `Int` here?

Comment: Agreed, that may well be a better design (depending on what the OP is actually trying to achieve)